# Mining Groups of people from Wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia, web-crawler

I am trying to get the list of people from the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:People_by_occupation . I have to go through all the sections and get people from each section.

How should i go about it ? Should I use a crawler and get the pages and search through those using BeautifulSoup ?
Or is there any other alternative to get the same from Wikipedia ?

Comment: Why do you *have* to?  Generally, mining for lists of people is not really appropriate.

Comment: I am trying some analysis on different group of people. We have news analysis data from which we have different feature for each entities  and what to see how important is particular feature for a particular group.

Comment: What is your preferred programming language?Python?

Comment: Yes. Python is my preferred programming language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with [Pywikipediabot](http://pywikipediabot.sourceforge.net/) python project.

Have a look to [category.py](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot/category.py).
You could use:

```
* tree        - show a tree of subcategories of a given category
* listify     - make a list of all of the articles that are in a category
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can just download the entire dump of the wikipedia and work it from there. The one your would probably want is only the [articles dump dated 3 feb 2010](http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20100130/). But beware: It's 5.6 GB in size.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using dump for processing categories. In this case OP should write wikipedia template processing since some categories are added through templates. I vote for crawling wikipedia pages.

Comment: Crawling such a big web site (and against the site policy) is not good idea. It is difficult to process the 
Wikipedia but passing an XML dump of it is not that bad, and I can assure you it can be done in 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CatScan tool to search categories.

Instructions here
http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/CatScan

[Example search](http://toolserver.org/~daniel/WikiSense/CategoryIntersect.php?wikilang=en&wikifam=.wikipedia.org&basecat=People+by+occupation&basedeep=2&templates=&mode=al&go=Scan&format=html&userlang=en) - note, html format maxes out at 1000 results. Choose CSV export to retrieve all the results. Also, be sure to modify the category depth and other options, as needed.

The pywikipediabot already mentioned is another option.